# How to create a QQ plot of azimuths to test rotational symmetry of a spherical point dataset?

Tags: matrix, circular-statistics

I am trying to do some Q-Q plots and the Kuiper test for rotational symmetry about the mean direction.  These are unit vector, spherical data.  What I am struggling to understand is the rotation from my own directions, where φ is the azimuth direction (0 to 360) and θ is the dip up/down direction (0 to 180), to the rotated/modified φ' and θ'. I'll limit this posting to the Q-Q plot question.

Here is a small example set of 10 azimuth/φ angles: 
146.6
198.0
182.5
148.5
183.0
130.5
344.9
355.5
82.3
166.2

So, first the graphical method: Q-Q plot. Images, including #1 below, are from Fisher, Lewis and Embleton 1987 (reference below). I have the φ values, but the plot requires the rotated/modified φ' values.

[image: graphical and formal tests]

Now below in Image #2 is the method for doing the rotation, equation 3.8.  I'm thinking I can set the ψ<sub>0</sub> to zero, so I could use the "simpler" equation 3.9.

[image: rotation equation]

But equations 3.8 or 3.9 require equations 3.5 and 3.6, which are below in Images #3 and #4 respectively.  I'm able to calculate the Resultant length (R) and x-,y- and z-hat, so I have those, and which allows me to get φ-hat and φ-hat.  So, I'm not sure what to do with equation 3.9 or 3.9, or how to rotate my numbers.  Any suggestions?  Apologies for the long post of images.

[image: equation 3.5, etc.]

[image: equation 3.6]

Fisher, N.I., T. Lewis and B.J.J. Embleton. 1987. Statistical Analysis of Spherical Data. Cambridge, Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want to study the azimuths of a set of spherical points $P_i$ relative to their spherical mean $\bar P$.  The most straightforward solution [solves the spherical triangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles#Solving_spherical_triangles) $(N,\bar P, P_i)$ where $N$ is the North Pole.

Let the co-latitudes of the points $P_i$ and $\bar P$ (angles from North) be $a$ and $b$ respectively.  Let $\gamma$ be the angle between them: it's just the difference between the longitudes of the same two points.  The azimuth, with due East being zero and orienting angles counterclockwise, is determined by

$$\arctan_2(\sin(b)\cos(a) - \cos(b)\sin(a)\cos(\gamma),\  \sin(a)\sin(\gamma))$$

where $\arctan_2(y,x)$ is the angle of a point $(x,y)$ in the plane.  (This is supposed to be a numerically stable version of the formula, but I haven't tested it extensively.)

In this example, $100$ points were generated according to a (symmetric) Fisher-von Mises distribution distributed throughout the southern and western hemispheres, along with another $50$ points focused in the south and east.  The resulting distribution is not symmetric.

[image: Figure showing points and the QQ plot of the azimuths.]

*The mean point is shown as a red triangle.*

Relative to the mean point, there is a cluster of points to its right (East) and upward (North), creating a swath of azimuths in the QQ plot between $0$ and $1$ (expressed in radians).  The diffuse cluster to its west creates a broader swath of azimuths between $3$ and $5$.  The QQ plot is clearly not uniform (for otherwise it would lie close to the dashed diagonal line), reflecting the bimodality of the spherical point distribution.

---

The `R` code that produced this example can be used to generate azimuthal QQ plots for any data.  It assumes the spherical coordinates are provided as *rows* in an array; the relevant rows are indexed by "phi" and "theta".

```r
#
# Spherical triangle, two sides and included angle given.
# Returns the angle `alpha` opposite `a`, in radians between 0 and 2*pi.
#
SAS <- function(a, gamma, b) {
  atan2(sin(b)*cos(a) - cos(b)*sin(a)*cos(gamma), sin(a)*sin(gamma)) %% (2*pi)
}
#
# Cartesian coordinate conversion (for generating points).
#
xyz.to.spherical <- function(xyz) {
  xyz <- matrix(xyz, nrow=3)
  x <- xyz[1,]; y <- xyz[2,]; z <- xyz[3,]
  r2 <- x^2 + y^2
  rho <- sqrt(r2 + z^2)
  theta <- pi/2 - atan2(z, sqrt(r2))
  phi <- atan2(y, x)
  theta[x==0 && y==0] <- sign(z) * pi/2
  return (rbind(rho, theta, phi))
}
#
# Generate random points on the sphere.
#
library(MASS)
set.seed(17)
n.1 <- 100
n.2 <- 50
mu.1 <- c(0,-1,-1/4) * 2        # Center of first distribution
mu.2 <- c(1,1,-1/2) * 5         # Center of the second distribution
Sigma <- outer(1:3, 1:3, "==")  # Identity covariance matrix
xyz.1 <- t(mvrnorm(n.1, mu.1, Sigma)) # Each column is a point
xyz.2 <- t(mvrnorm(n.2, mu.2, Sigma))
xyz <- cbind(xyz.1, xyz.2)      # The Cartesian coordinates
rtf <- xyz.to.spherical(xyz)    # The spherical coordinates (also in columns)
#
# Compute the spherical mean and the azimuths relative to that mean.
#
mean.rtf <- xyz.to.spherical(rowMeans(xyz))
a <- SAS(rtf["theta",], rtf["phi",]-mean.rtf["phi",], mean.rtf["theta",])
#
# Plot the data and a QQ plot of the azimuths.
#
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(c(-pi, pi), c(-1,1), type="n", 
     xlab="Phi", ylab="Cos(theta)", main="Sample points and their mean")
abline(h=0, col="Gray") # The Equator
abline(v=0, col="Gray") # The Prime Meridian
points(rtf["phi",], cos(rtf["theta", ]), col="#00000080")
points(mean.rtf["phi",], cos(mean.rtf["theta",]), bg="Red", pch=24, cex=1.25)

plot(c(0,1), c(0,2*pi), type="n",
     xlab="Quantile", ylab="Azimuth", main="Azimuthal QQ Plot")
abline(c(0, 2*pi), lty=3, lwd=2, col="Gray")
points(seq(0, 1, along.with=a), sort(a))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still confused though. What is the subscript 2 on the equation beginning with arctan signifying? What do I do with that comma in the middle of the same equation? Or, what do I do with the two separate parts within the arctan calculation?

My azimuths have 0 at the top, and then proceed clockwise around the equator.  The Q-Q plot I'm interested in only uses the azimuths, but for my altitude/dip/co-latitude angles I use -90 to 0 (S hemisphere) and 0 to 90 (N hemisphere) rather than 0-180, for esoteric archaeological reasons.

I've been using R since Dec. & the code is over my head

Comment: Regarding the R code, so I would put my angles in two rows, say in a csv file made in excel? Say, call cell A1 phi and A2 theta, with the actual data following horizontally in each row? I can never (initially) understand how to simply set up data in R so whatever function I'm using will use it. It's trial and error. Where is the name of the file (array name?) that I need to call my data so that R knows where to find theta and phi in them? In other instances I've done it where a dataset is called something, say x, and then the column with the relevant numbers is given as x$example.

Comment: Arctangent functions come in two flavours, with one and two arguments. A two argument version is needed to give results covering the entire circle. @Whuber's notation with subscript 2 echoes one often used in software where some function name like ATAN2 is used. For more see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html

Comment: Your specific questions in comments about basic difficulties in setting this up in R are pointing off-topic. There is a fine line here: @whuber's answer explained principles and provided code as back-up, but once the focus is entirely on code Cross Validated is no longer the best forum. See the Help Center for guidance on software-related questions.

Comment: Indeed the R name `atan2()` encapsulates the same distinction.